# Docker Container Volume not Mount with Host System

Tags: docker

I am trying to mount my blackbox exporter config with host but its give me error.

```
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:45.378Z caller=main.go:212 msg="Starting blackbox_exporter" version="(version=0.18.0, branch=HEAD, revision=60c86e6ce5a1111f7958b06ae7a08222bb6ec839)"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:45.378Z caller=main.go:213 msg="Build context" (gogo1.15.2,userroot@53d72328d93f,date20201012-09:46:31)=(MISSING)
blackbox-exporter    | level=error ts=2020-12-24T11:07:45.378Z caller=main.go:216 msg="Error loading config" err="error reading config file: open /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml: no such file or directory"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:47.350Z caller=main.go:212 msg="Starting blackbox_exporter" version="(version=0.18.0, branch=HEAD, revision=60c86e6ce5a1111f7958b06ae7a08222bb6ec839)"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:47.351Z caller=main.go:213 msg="Build context" (gogo1.15.2,userroot@53d72328d93f,date20201012-09:46:31)=(MISSING)
blackbox-exporter    | level=error ts=2020-12-24T11:07:47.351Z caller=main.go:216 msg="Error loading config" err="error reading config file: open /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml: no such file or directory"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:48.748Z caller=main.go:212 msg="Starting blackbox_exporter" version="(version=0.18.0, branch=HEAD, revision=60c86e6ce5a1111f7958b06ae7a08222bb6ec839)"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:48.749Z caller=main.go:213 msg="Build context" (gogo1.15.2,userroot@53d72328d93f,date20201012-09:46:31)=(MISSING)
blackbox-exporter    | level=error ts=2020-12-24T11:07:48.750Z caller=main.go:216 msg="Error loading config" err="error reading config file: open /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml: no such file or directory"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:49.810Z caller=main.go:212 msg="Starting blackbox_exporter" version="(version=0.18.0, branch=HEAD, revision=60c86e6ce5a1111f7958b06ae7a08222bb6ec839)"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:49.810Z caller=main.go:213 msg="Build context" (gogo1.15.2,userroot@53d72328d93f,date20201012-09:46:31)=(MISSING)
blackbox-exporter    | level=error ts=2020-12-24T11:07:49.810Z caller=main.go:216 msg="Error loading config" err="error reading config file: open /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml: no such file or directory"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:51.169Z caller=main.go:212 msg="Starting blackbox_exporter" version="(version=0.18.0, branch=HEAD, revision=60c86e6ce5a1111f7958b06ae7a08222bb6ec839)"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:51.169Z caller=main.go:213 msg="Build context" (gogo1.15.2,userroot@53d72328d93f,date20201012-09:46:31)=(MISSING)
blackbox-exporter    | level=error ts=2020-12-24T11:07:51.169Z caller=main.go:216 msg="Error loading config" err="error reading config file: open /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml: no such file or directory"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:53.325Z caller=main.go:212 msg="Starting blackbox_exporter" version="(version=0.18.0, branch=HEAD, revision=60c86e6ce5a1111f7958b06ae7a08222bb6ec839)"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:53.325Z caller=main.go:213 msg="Build context" (gogo1.15.2,userroot@53d72328d93f,date20201012-09:46:31)=(MISSING)
blackbox-exporter    | level=error ts=2020-12-24T11:07:53.325Z caller=main.go:216 msg="Error loading config" err="error reading config file: open /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml: no such file or directory"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:57.099Z caller=main.go:212 msg="Starting blackbox_exporter" version="(version=0.18.0, branch=HEAD, revision=60c86e6ce5a1111f7958b06ae7a08222bb6ec839)"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:57.099Z caller=main.go:213 msg="Build context" (gogo1.15.2,userroot@53d72328d93f,date20201012-09:46:31)=(MISSING)
blackbox-exporter    | level=error ts=2020-12-24T11:07:57.099Z caller=main.go:216 msg="Error loading config" err="error reading config file: open /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml: no such file or directory"
blackbox-exporter exited with code 1
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:45.378Z caller=main.go:212 msg="Starting blackbox_exporter" version="(version=0.18.0, branch=HEAD, revision=60c86e6ce5a1111f7958b06ae7a08222bb6ec839)"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:45.378Z caller=main.go:213 msg="Build context" (gogo1.15.2,userroot@53d72328d93f,date20201012-09:46:31)=(MISSING)
blackbox-exporter    | level=error ts=2020-12-24T11:07:45.378Z caller=main.go:216 msg="Error loading config" err="error reading config file: open /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml: no such file or directory"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:47.350Z caller=main.go:212 msg="Starting blackbox_exporter" version="(version=0.18.0, branch=HEAD, revision=60c86e6ce5a1111f7958b06ae7a08222bb6ec839)"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:47.351Z caller=main.go:213 msg="Build context" (gogo1.15.2,userroot@53d72328d93f,date20201012-09:46:31)=(MISSING)
blackbox-exporter    | level=error ts=2020-12-24T11:07:47.351Z caller=main.go:216 msg="Error loading config" err="error reading config file: open /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml: no such file or directory"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:48.748Z caller=main.go:212 msg="Starting blackbox_exporter" version="(version=0.18.0, branch=HEAD, revision=60c86e6ce5a1111f7958b06ae7a08222bb6ec839)"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:48.749Z caller=main.go:213 msg="Build context" (gogo1.15.2,userroot@53d72328d93f,date20201012-09:46:31)=(MISSING)
blackbox-exporter    | level=error ts=2020-12-24T11:07:48.750Z caller=main.go:216 msg="Error loading config" err="error reading config file: open /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml: no such file or directory"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:49.810Z caller=main.go:212 msg="Starting blackbox_exporter" version="(version=0.18.0, branch=HEAD, revision=60c86e6ce5a1111f7958b06ae7a08222bb6ec839)"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:49.810Z caller=main.go:213 msg="Build context" (gogo1.15.2,userroot@53d72328d93f,date20201012-09:46:31)=(MISSING)
blackbox-exporter    | level=error ts=2020-12-24T11:07:49.810Z caller=main.go:216 msg="Error loading config" err="error reading config file: open /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml: no such file or directory"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:51.169Z caller=main.go:212 msg="Starting blackbox_exporter" version="(version=0.18.0, branch=HEAD, revision=60c86e6ce5a1111f7958b06ae7a08222bb6ec839)"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:51.169Z caller=main.go:213 msg="Build context" (gogo1.15.2,userroot@53d72328d93f,date20201012-09:46:31)=(MISSING)
blackbox-exporter    | level=error ts=2020-12-24T11:07:51.169Z caller=main.go:216 msg="Error loading config" err="error reading config file: open /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml: no such file or directory"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:53.325Z caller=main.go:212 msg="Starting blackbox_exporter" version="(version=0.18.0, branch=HEAD, revision=60c86e6ce5a1111f7958b06ae7a08222bb6ec839)"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:53.325Z caller=main.go:213 msg="Build context" (gogo1.15.2,userroot@53d72328d93f,date20201012-09:46:31)=(MISSING)
blackbox-exporter    | level=error ts=2020-12-24T11:07:53.325Z caller=main.go:216 msg="Error loading config" err="error reading config file: open /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml: no such file or directory"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:57.099Z caller=main.go:212 msg="Starting blackbox_exporter" version="(version=0.18.0, branch=HEAD, revision=60c86e6ce5a1111f7958b06ae7a08222bb6ec839)"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:07:57.099Z caller=main.go:213 msg="Build context" (gogo1.15.2,userroot@53d72328d93f,date20201012-09:46:31)=(MISSING)
blackbox-exporter    | level=error ts=2020-12-24T11:07:57.099Z caller=main.go:216 msg="Error loading config" err="error reading config file: open /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml: no such file or directory"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:08:04.049Z caller=main.go:212 msg="Starting blackbox_exporter" version="(version=0.18.0, branch=HEAD, revision=60c86e6ce5a1111f7958b06ae7a08222bb6ec839)"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:08:04.049Z caller=main.go:213 msg="Build context" (gogo1.15.2,userroot@53d72328d93f,date20201012-09:46:31)=(MISSING)
blackbox-exporter    | level=error ts=2020-12-24T11:08:04.049Z caller=main.go:216 msg="Error loading config" err="error reading config file: open /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml: no such file or directory"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:08:17.378Z caller=main.go:212 msg="Starting blackbox_exporter" version="(version=0.18.0, branch=HEAD, revision=60c86e6ce5a1111f7958b06ae7a08222bb6ec839)"
blackbox-exporter    | level=info ts=2020-12-24T11:08:17.378Z caller=main.go:213 msg="Build context" (gogo1.15.2,userroot@53d72328d93f,date20201012-09:46:31)=(MISSING)
blackbox-exporter    | level=error ts=2020-12-24T11:08:17.378Z caller=main.go:216 msg="Error loading config" err="error reading config file: open /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml: no such file or directory"
```

Here is my Docker Compose file:

```yaml
  blackbox_exporter:
    image: prom/blackbox-exporter
    container_name: blackbox-exporter
    volumes:
      - /etc/blackboxexporter/:/home/huzaifakhan/dockprom/prometheus/
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml'
    restart: unless-stopped
    dns: 8.8.8.8
    expose:
      - 9115
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"
```

Comment: Can you attach to the container and send me directories inside it through below command 
"docker exec -it blackbox_exporter /bin/bash ".

Answer (score 0):

In the `volumes:` section in your `docker-compose` file, switch the places of the directories. The host directory should come first, then the container directory.

AND, the `config.yml` must exist in the host directory. Just copy and paste it to the host from the container by running:

```
docker exec <container-name> cat /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml
```

Basically, in the end, it should look like this:

```
volumes:
    - /home/.../your-directory:/etc/container-directory
```

`/home/.../your-directory` should contain the `config.yml` file

If this is the case, you will have the config file in the `/etc/container-direcory` when it is running and won't get the error above.

Comment: I also try to place host directory first then container directory but no effect on it.

Comment: @huzaifa224 I initially misunderstood the problem, edited the answer.